# Cross Reference Sources Technology

Tags: publications

I'm curious to know if there's any existing technologies for taking a list of journal publications (PDFs), stripping out the bibliography into discrete items, and cumulating a list of cross references and "academic influencers". Or is there any advice on how to implement such rather easily?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for [softwarerecs.se], not a question about academia.

Comment: I think ASE should be open to such questions.  It's not like someone is asking emacs vs vi.  They're asking if such technology exists, and it pertains to academic references.  I'd like to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you / your institution has access to databases like Thomson Reuter's *Web of Science*, you actually not only find the abstracted publications (like the *present tense*), but the references cited by them (similar to the *past tense*, at the moment of their publication) and who cited this work (and hence, was influenced by this publication).

*Web of Science* allows you to export the results of your bibliographic research, but not only as *.bib or *.ris for your reference manager like [zotero](https://www.zotero.org/)/[EndNote](http://endnote.com/)/[papers](http://papersapp.com/), but equally in a format accessible to [vosviewer](http://www.vosviewer.com) and [CitNetExplorer](http://www.citnetexplorer.nl/) as tools for [bibliometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliometrics).  With the later, you may venture out how groups influence each other by collaboration / co-authorship

[image]

([source](http://www.vosviewer.com/features/screenshots))

but the historical dimension, too:

[image]

([source](http://www.citnetexplorer.nl/screenshots))

As it takes only one export (from *Web of Science*) for the two programs, and because their views complement each other, I like to deploy both of them for a more "rounded picture".